# Ruby rcurry. How I can implement proc "right" currying?

Tags: ruby, lambda, closures, proc, currying

I'm working in a new gem to extend the Ruby Core classes, something similar to [Active Support Core Extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) or [Powerpack](https://github.com/bbatsov/powerpack). These days I'm working on the `Proc` class, for example I added [closure composition](http://arturoherrero.com/closure-design-patterns-ruby-edition/#closure-composition).

But today I like to talk about currying. This is the Ruby standard library functionality for `curry`:

```
describe "#curry" do
  it "returns a curried proc" do
    modulus = ->(mod, num) { num % mod }
    mod2 = modulus.curry[2]
    expect(mod2.call(5)).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

I like to add a new `rcurry` method to support proc "right" currying to pass the following spec. It's the same issue reported a few months ago, [Proc/Method#rcurry working like curry but in reverse order](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11161).

```
describe "#rcurry" do
  it "returns a right curried proc" do
    modulus = ->(mod, num) { num % mod }
    mod2 = modulus.rcurry[2]
    expect(mod2.call(5)).to eq(2)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa my question is how implement `rcurry`.

Comment: So you want someone to write code for you so that you can publish that as a gem?

Comment: Publish or not publish a gem is just a byproduct. The important thing here is the knowledge. I got stuck solving the problem or what is the right approach that I should take. Anyway, if the main thing here is the creation of the gem, I encourage you to create a gem supporting `rcurry` with the [Jordan answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34082091/462015).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way to solve this is to first solve an easier problem: How do we implement our own`curry`?

One important thing you may or may not know is that `Proc#[]` is an alias for `Proc#call`, so in the above code `modulus.curry[2]` is the same as `modulus.curry.call(2)`. Just for clarity I'm going to use `.call` in the code below.

Here's the first bit of code from your spec:

```
modulus = ->(mod, num) { num % mod }
mod2 = modulus.curry.call(2)
```

The second line tells us that `modulus.curry` returns a Proc (because we invoke `call` on it), so we know our method definition will look a bit like this:

```
class Proc
  def curry_b
    proc do |*passed|
      # ???
    end
  end
end
```

Now when we call `modulus.curry.call(2)`, the value of `passed` in the innermost block will be `[ 2 ]` (an array because we used the splat operator).

Here's the next part of your code:

```
mod2 = modulus.curry.call(2)
expect(mod2.call(5)).to eq(1)
```

Here we see that `modulus.curry.call(2)` itself returns a Proc, so now our method looks like this:

```
def curry_b
  proc do |*passed|
    proc do |*args|
      # ??
    end
  end
end
```

Now when we call `mod2.call(5)`, the value of `args` in the innermost block will be `[ 5 ]`.

So we have `[ 2 ]` in `passed` and `[ 5 ]` in `args`. We want the return value of `mod2.call(5)` to be the same as the return value of `modulus.call(2, 5)`—in other words, `modulus.call(*passed, *args)`. In our method , `modulus` is `self`, so we just have to do this:

```
def curry_b
  proc do |*passed|
    proc do |*args|
      self.call(*passed, *args)
    end
  end
end
```

Now we can shorten it a bit and try it out:

```
class Proc
  def curry_b
    proc do |*passed|
      proc {|*args| self[*passed, *args] }
    end
  end
end

mod2 = modulus.curry_b[2]
puts mod2.call(5)
# => 1
```

We've reimplemented `curry`! How, then, do we implement `rcurry`? Well, the only difference is that `rcurry` puts the curried arguments at the end instead of the beginning, so believe it or not we just have to switch `passed` and `args` around:

```
class Proc
  def rcurry
    proc do |*passed|
      proc {|*args| self[*args, *passed] }
    end
  end
end

modulus = ->(mod, num) { num % mod }
mod2 = modulus.rcurry[2]
p mod2.call(5)
# => 2
```

Of course, this isn't perfect: Unlike `Proc#curry` `curry_b` and `rcurry` don't take an *arity* argument. That shouldn't be too tough, so I'll leave it as an exercise for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately only works with two arguments but is a very good starting point. Eg, this fails: `b = ->(x, y, z) { (x||0) + (y||0) + (z||0) }` `expect(b.curry_b.call(1).call(2).call(3)).to eq(6)`.